# Email from php being sent as boscustweb3203.eigbox.net

Tags: php, email

I have created a file to send email but each time I sent a test email I am getting the domain name of email as `boscustweb3203.eigbox.net`.

The code I have used is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>

<style>
.error{
color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameerr = $emailerr = $gendererr = $commenterr = $websiteerr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])){
        $namerrr = "Name is required";
        } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
        }}
        if (empty($_POST["email"])){
        $emailerr = "Email is required";
        } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }}

        if (empty($_POST["website"])){
        $websiteerr = "Website name is required";
        } else {
        $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
            // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) 
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL";
        }

        if (empty($_POST["comment"])){
        $commenterr = "Comment is required";
        } else {
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
        }

        if (empty($_POST["gender"])){
        $gendererr = "Gender is required";
        } else {
        $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
        }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name: <input type="text" name="name">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $nameerr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $emailerr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Website: <input type="text" name="website">
   <span class = "error"><?php echo $websiteerr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <span class = "error"><?php echo $commenterr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <span class="error"><?php echo $gendererr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>


<?php
$to = "testemail@gmail.com";
$headers = "From: $name \r\n";
mail($to,$website, $comment, $headers);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

The host of my server is `ipage.com`. Please let me know if this kind of bug or a server issue.

I get email from `username@boscustweb3203.eigbox.net`. I have given different email address. The first part before `@` is correct though.

Comment: It seems that your are using a name instead of an email address as "From".

Comment: Thanks that seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're only setting a name for the From header:

```
$headers = "From: $name \r\n";
```

PHP is automatically appending an e-mail URL. You should always specify a fully qualified e-mail address in the From: header.

Consult the manuals:

- **http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.mail.php**
- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php**

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but I'll just add a comment here since it's already been "answered" - `$headers = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";`